# How to filter with jquery and search for upper- and lowercase?

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, filter, uppercase, lowercase

I have a code for filtering my searchresults using 2 inputs. I am using jquery for this.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".search").keyup(function () {

        $(".searchli").hide();

        if ($("#refine").val() != "") {
            var term = $("#search").val() + " " + $("#refine").val();
        } else {
            var term = $("#search").val();
        }

        $("li:contains('" + term + "')").show();
    });
});    
</script>

Search: <input type="search" id="search" class="search" length="24" />
Refine    <input type="search" id="refine" class="search" length="24" />
```

My list with results contain Uppercases and Lowercases.
My problem is that I can't search in lowercases (type keywords in lowercase) It can't find any results then.

How can I add `toLowerCase()` or `toUpperCase()` to my code so it will work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the jQuery contains selector to ignore case using this snippet found on [this page](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/make-jquery-contains-case-insensitive/):

```
$.expr[":"].contains = $.expr.createPseudo(function(arg) {
    return function( elem ) {
        return $(elem).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(arg.toUpperCase()) >= 0;
    };
});
```

Alternatively you could create a new selector instead of overriding :contains (which could theoretically cause weird behaviour in other scripts) by calling it :containsInvariant or something.

**EDIT**: This wasn't compatible with all versions of jQuery, so [here's one](https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/wiki/Sizzle-Documentation#wiki-back-compat) that should work across all versions:

```
// An implementation of a case-insensitive contains pseudo
// made for all versions of jQuery
(function( $ ) {

function icontains( elem, text ) {
    return (
        elem.textContent ||
        elem.innerText ||
        $( elem ).text() ||
        ""
    ).toLowerCase().indexOf( (text || "").toLowerCase() ) > -1;
}

$.expr[':'].icontains = $.expr.createPseudo ?
    $.expr.createPseudo(function( text ) {
        return function( elem ) {
            return icontains( elem, text );
        };
    }) :
    function( elem, i, match ) {
        return icontains( elem, match[3] );
    };

})( jQuery );
```

Comment: Where do I have to put this? I have a jquery.min.js file so I don't know.

Comment: @KeesSonnema Put it at the beginning of your own script.  It doesn't matter much, but before `document.ready` makes most sense.

Comment: Using v1.9 jquery.min.js and add it just above my $(document).ready, But function isn't working anymore now.

Comment: @KeesSonnema Strange.  That should be okay.  Are there any error messages in the console?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'createPseudo'

Comment: See the link he gave you - it has alternative code for running on versions > 1.8

Comment: @KeesSonnema - see my edit with a new code snippet that should work across all versions of jQuery. The jQuery developers chose to break the createPseudo function in 1.8+ http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/12409

Comment: My function is working again. but I still get the same problem. I can't search with lowercases.

Comment: Sorry, the snippet I gave you has the selector :icontains and not :contains. Switch your line to use that selector and it should work.

Comment: It works now. but my function isn't really working like I want. Can you help me in chat? I will accept your answer now.

Answer (score 0):

Use [this](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/make-jquery-contains-case-insensitive/) to patch the Contains function to be case insensive...

**Edit** - Here's the code

```
// NEW selector
jQuery.expr[':'].Contains = function(a, i, m) {
    return jQuery(a).text().toUpperCase()
        .indexOf(m[3].toUpperCase()) >= 0;
};

// OVERWRITES old selecor
jQuery.expr[':'].contains = function(a, i, m) {
    return jQuery(a).text().toUpperCase()
        .indexOf(m[3].toUpperCase()) >= 0;
};
```

JQuery 1.8 version

```
$.expr[":"].contains = $.expr.createPseudo(function(arg) {
    return function( elem ) {
        return $(elem).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(arg.toUpperCase()) >= 0;
    };
});
```

Comment: Where do I have to put this :)?